# If properties.Afterproperties["ContentType"] is null, is it safe to assume that the item is a document?

Tags: content-type, document, file-upload

I need to add a specific behavior in the ItemAdding event when the item added is a document, but I noticed that when using the "Upload document" or the "Upload Multiple Documents" features in Sharepoint 2010, properties.Afterproperties["ContentType"] and properties.Afterproperties["ContentTypeId"] are null. So my question is simple, is it safe then to assume that the item being added is a document? and if not, then how can I find out if it is a document?

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the List property, then detect if the event is occuring in a document library.